# sprintf format warnings when compiling

Tags: c, format, printf

Variable `freq` is declared as follows:

```
void exciteFreqN(float freq, unsigned short N)
```

then I use the following instruction:

```
sprintf(debugstr, "Cntr ticks:%d freq:%1.1f\r\n", ctphp, freq);
```

Format specifier `"%1.1f"` for `freq` is clearly `float` (I think).
However, the compiler warns:

```
acquisitionXBEE.c: In function 'exciteFreqN':
***acquisitionXBEE.c:8519:5: warning: format '%1.1f' expects type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'float'
```

Why `"%1.1f"` expects `double`? Shouldn't `"f"` stand for float?
How can I get rid of that warning?

Comment: Is it your compiler or IDE giving this warning?  What compiler/IDE version?

Comment: it should be implicitly converted to double. But `printf` "%f" expects `double`.

Comment: @Guille It looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: @dbush Those look like compiler messges, not IDE.

Comment: Does it work in spite of the warning?

Comment: We need following information: your platform, IDE, compiler and versions.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're getting the warning "format '%1.1f' expects type 'double', but argument has type 'float'"?  For a call to `sprintf`?  This is a staggeringly awful mistake for your compiler or IDE to be making — it's just really, really, wrong.  (Note I'm not talking about your code, which from what I can see is fine.  Your compiler or IDE is really, really wrong to be complaining about it in this way.)

Comment: @Jabberwocky
Yes, I am sure about the warning, I just copied&pasted messages from my computer. I am using MPLAB X IDE software with a compiler tool chain XC16 ver 1.61

Answer (score 1):

> Why %1.1f expects double? Shouldn't "f" stand for float? How can I get rid of that warning?

`"%1.1f"` expects a `double` as specified by the C standard.
In  C, `double` is the default floating-point type for FP `...` arguments and constants.

`...` arguments of type `float` are converted to `double` before being passed.  `sprintf(debugstr, "%1.1f  %1.1f   %1.1f ", 1.0, 2.0f, freq);` should work.

Think of `"%f"` implying *fixed-point* format for floating-point, not `float`.

Compiler is buggy or simply designed that way and therefore non-compliant to C.

A cast may quiet the warning:

```
sprintf(debugstr, "Cntr ticks:%d freq:%1.1f\r\n", ctphp, (double) freq);
```

Report bug and/or move to another compiler.

Note: If the non-compliant compiler purposely does not promote `float` to `double` when a `...` argument, `sprintf()` may support, as an extension, some flag, like `"%$f"` to indicate the argument is a `float`.  Check your compiler documents.  Be wary then of making such implementation specific code.

---

**Warning**

Even on a working machine `sprintf(debugstr, "Cntr ticks:%d freq:%1.1f\r\n", ctphp, freq);` is scary as the buffer may overrun with a large `freq` like `FLT_MAX`.

Control width, size and be more informative.  What good is a debug message that causes a buffer overflow or is not so informative?

```
// snprintf,       v----size-----v                      %g
snprintf(debugstr, sizeof debugstr, "Cntr ticks:%d freq:%g\r\n", ctphp, freq);
// ... or pedantically to see all useful precision
snprintf(debugstr, sizeof debugstr, "Cntr ticks:%d freq:%.*g\r\n", 
    ctphp, FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, freq);
```